# Android: memory leak in an asynctask

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

I have the following code for an AsyncTask which is located on a separate Java file (not inner class):

```
public class LastPriceRetrieval extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

    private String itemName;

    public LastPriceRetrieval() {
        Utils.incAsync();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            itemName = strings[0];
            URL url = new URL("<url>?q=" + itemName);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            String body = stringBuilder.toString();
            reader.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            if (!body.contains("\"price\"")) return "0";
            else {
                body = body.substring(body.indexOf("\"price\""));
                body = body.substring(body.indexOf("=\"") + 2);
                return body.substring(0, body.indexOf("\"") - 1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "0";
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String resLastPrice) {
        if (Double.valueOf(resLastPrice) != 0) {
            Utils.db.setLastPrice(itemName, Double.valueOf(resLastPrice));
        }
        Utils.decAsync();
    }
}
```

Utils class is as follow (again a file on its own, not inner class)

```
public class Utils {

    private static int asyncs = 0;
    private static db = null;

    public static synchronized void incAsync() {
        asyncs++;
    }

    public static synchronized void decAsync() {
        asyncs--;
    }

    public static int getAsyncs() {
        return asyncs;
    }
}
```

I call the above asynctask 60 times in parallel (different itemName)

```
new LastPriceRetrieval().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, itemName);
```

Utils.db is a sqlite class which I instantiate in MainActivity's onCreate. I do nothing while the 60 asynctasks are running, just show a ProgressDialog and waiting for it to finish.

I run a memory monitor and when all the 60 asynctasks are done, the app takes more memory than before, meaning something is leaking, not sure why or what. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe call gc() before you try to test memory leaks?

Comment: Because each call (I tried 3 times in a row) raised up the memory usage, I don't think forcing the GC will work. I see the memory goes up and down while the 60 calls are being processed. I thought it will calm down near the number it was before but it goes up by 1-2mb every process (60 calls).

Comment: If you add in.close() before reader.close() is it make the situation better?

Comment: javadoc: reader.close() -> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it.